# C# Error Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
//other streamreader code
var splitsByLine = content.Split('\n');
        foreach (var s in splitsByLine)
        {
            var nameAndSize = s.Split(',');
            FileNameAndSizes.Add(nameAndSize[0], Convert.ToInt64(nameAndSize[1]));
        }

        foreach (var item in FileNameAndSizes)
        {
            if(File.Exists(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "cleo",  item.Key)))
            {
                FileInfo f = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "cleo", item.Key));
                var s1 = f.Length;

                if (s1 != item.Value)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(f.Name + " modified file, please change it to default");
                }
            }
        }
```

When I run code, i have error in this code:

```
FileNameAndSizes.Add(nameAndSize[0], Convert.ToInt64(nameAndSize[1]));
```

**Index was outside the bounds of the array.** and something about 0x0.. I'm C# newbie, how can i fix it?

It's content value:

```
AnimModByxXx2o1o.cs, 18616
anims.cs, 18780
Dance.cs, 18661
emergencylights.cs, 32213
fps-de-limiter.cs, 17575
neon.cs, 19019
StreamMemFix.cs, 17560
sun.cs, 17662
WEATHERMENUE.cs, 18437
anim.cs, 17637
anim[0].cs, 20684
anim_0_.cs, 19392
anim1.cs, 18744
anim2.cs, 19012
Anim4.cs, 22900
anim228.cs, 19465
```

P.S I'm tested it with two files:
First file (current) is getting value from mysql, prints it, and then I need to read value with C# app
Second file (working) is create custom file write to it this content, and it's work ok :?

Comment: When you split the variable s you are not getting two elements in the array nameAndSize, please check your input

Comment: post what's content value?

Comment: Clearly some of your lines don't contain a comma.

Comment: Have you Googled the exception to make an effort to understand what it is and why it's happening? With that knowledge, you should be able to step through your code and identify the issue.

Comment: make sure that your content doesn't have an empty line and for each line make sure that there is a comma flowed by a white space

Comment: The time required to put a breakpoint, start the debugger and run your code is usually a lot less than the time to write a question and wait that someone has the right guess. If your content variable is the one showed above then this error should not happen unless an empty line is present after the last one. (A guess as you can see)

Comment: While you're at it, you should look at File.ReadAllLines or StreamReader.ReadLine to try and get rid of that content.Split('\n').

Comment: Yep guys I have null line, thanks so much

Comment: Don't remove the text of your question in an edit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do simple tests to ensure your values before try to work with them:

http://ideone.com/Iyle5C

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        //other streamreader code
            string[] splitsByLine = new string[] { "AnimModByxXx2o1o.cs, 18616", 
                                                   "anims.cs, 18780", 
                                                   "Dance.cs, 18661", 
                                                   "emergencylights.cs, 32213", 
                                                   "fps-de-limiter.cs, 17575", 
                                                   "neon.cs, 19019", 
                                                   "StreamMemFix.cs, 17560", 
                                                   "sun.cs, 17662", 
                                                   "WEATHERMENUE.cs, 18437", 
                                                   "anim.cs, 17637", 
                                                   "anim[0].cs, 20684", 
                                                   "anim_0_.cs, 19392", 
                                                   "anim1.cs, 18744", 
                                                   "anim2.cs, 19012", 
                                                   "Anim4.cs, 22900", 
                                                   "anim228.cs, 19465", 
                                                    "" };

            if (splitsByLine != null && splitsByLine.Any()) // Test
            {
                foreach (string s in splitsByLine)
                {
                    var nameAndSize = s.Split(',');

                    if (nameAndSize != null && nameAndSize.Any() && nameAndSize.Count() > 1) // Test
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(String.Concat(nameAndSize[0], " - ", Convert.ToInt64(nameAndSize[1])));

                        //FileNameAndSizes.Add(nameAndSize[0], Convert.ToInt64(nameAndSize[1]));
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```